# Redirect pages from subdomain to the same full path on main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have many pages with the following type of paths and subdomains:

```
place1.maindomain.com/travel/place1/go/
place2.maindomain.com/travel/place2/go/

place1.maindomain.com/travel/place1/widgets/
place2.maindomain.com/travel/place2/widgets/
```

I want to make all of these domains redirect automatically with a wildcard to the www and not the subdomain, so they would appear as follows:

```
www.maindomain.com/travel/place1/go/
www.maindomain.com/travel/place2/go/

www.maindomain.com/travel/place1/widgets/
www.maindomain.com/travel/place2/widgets/
```

My programmer has tried but he says he cannot do it. Is there a reason this type of subdomain wildcard redirect is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is easy. What's preventing you from just doing something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If you mean tha tthe "place1" part must match the "place1" part in the path, then you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}|%1 ^([^.]+)\.maindomain\.com|\1$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: There's no required connection between the 'place1' subdomain and the 'place1' in the path, it just needs to be a wildcard... that was just to demonstrate. The solution you have there looks the same as the ones we have tried, but will try it again. I wonder perhaps if the issue is with the existing rules, or which there are many. If we put this rule at the top of .htaccess file it will be prioritised I assume?